# Why does viewWillTransitionToSize: not fire on iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I've noticed that the view orientation method viewWillTransitionToSize will not fire on the iPad pro (both 9.7 and 12.9 inch) but it does fire on the iPad Air and Air 2

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
}
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: What is the version of OS on iPad pro?

Comment: Try to override method and check once

Comment: override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    // Your other code ...
}

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I'm using objective-c. there are no override methods. I'm using iOS 9